# Get all values of premade struct? C#

Tags: c#, struct

In C# I have a VERY huge struct, and I want to iterate through it easily, instead of manually typing them.

I tried using:

```
Type structType = typeof(myStruct);
System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] fields = structType.GetFields();
for(int i=0; i<fields.Length-1; i++)
{
    richTextBox1.Text += fields[i].Name + "\n";
}
```

where myStruct is the huge struct, but you can't pass variable structs to that, only the structs them selves.

Basically what I want to do is:

```
public struct myStruct
{
    public string myName;
    public int myAge;
    ...
    ...
}

//in code
myStruct a = readStructFromFile( filename );
string text = "";
foreach(field in a)
{
    text += field.name + ": " + file.value;
}
```

That possible?

Comment: This should not be a struct, frankly. Everything is wrong here: it is too large, it is mutable, and it has public fields. This is a big mistake - typically a mistake made by c/c++ devs dabbling in c# - did I guess right?

Comment: @MarcGravell He's probably gone by now.

Comment: @Romoku maybe they'll notice the comment when they come back to ask about their memory problem...

Comment: @MarcGravell: An exposed field struct is a fixed set of independent variables bound together with duct tape so they can be used individually or as one big variable.  If what one *wants* is for a variable of type `Foo` to encapsulate a fixed set of discrete values, and if one needs to both be able to copy all the values from one variable to another and be able to change one of the values within a variable, an exposed-field struct will fulfill both needs.  Is there some pattern I don't know of for writing classes which can do both operations nicely?  The only patterns I know of...

Comment: ...allow one to pick one of the operations to be efficient, but then make the other operation very awkward.  The more independent values should be encapsulated by the variable, the more awkward the inconvenient operation will become.  Structures are not class objects, and must be used differently from class objects, but in cases where structures that encapsulate a fixed set of values have advantages over class objects, those advantages mostly increase with size unless until things get really big (over 4K or so).

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm just retrieving data, it's all from a fixed input too.

Comment: @user1594121 that has nothing *whatsoever* to do with the choice of strict vs class in .net

Answer (score 2):

Use [`FieldInfo.GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue.aspx). Bigger structs really should be classes since structs are [meant to be small](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx).

```
myStruct a = readStructFromFile( filename );

Type structType = typeof(myStruct);
System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] fields = structType.GetFields();

var builder = new StringBuilder();

foreach(var field in fields)
{
    builder.Append(string.Format("{0} {1}\n",
                                 field.Name,
                                 field.GetValue(a).ToString());

}

richTextBox1.Text += builder.ToString();
```

Comment: You probably want to use `StringBuilder` or a lambda statement to build the string for the `RichTextBox`. As it stands, this example is an implementation of the inefficient [Shlemiel the painter's algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html).

Comment: Be careful - you are boxing **per field** - very bad idea for a fat struct with lots of fields /cc @user

Comment: MSDN, for whatever reason, fails to mention that structs have two distinct usage cases, exemplified by `Decimal` and `Drawing.Point`; things which encapsulate a single logical value should either be small structs or immutable classes.  Things which encapsulate a fixed set of independent values (e.g. the coordinates of a point) should be exposed-field structs of whatever size is needed to accommodate them.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to write some simple code-generation routines to generate something close to the code you want and copy it to the clipboard.  Then paste it into your program and make whatever little tweaks are required.

Having to write large amounts of boilerplate code usually implies a design deficiency either in what you're doing or in the language/framework you're using.  Depending upon exactly what you're doing, the fault could be in either the former or the latter.

There are situations where large structures are appropriate; if each variable of some type is supposed to encapsulate a fixed collection of independent values, an exposed-field structure expresses that perfectly.  Until things start getting so big as to create a risk of stack overflow, the factors which favor using a 4-field structures over a 4-field class will be even more significant with a 20-field structure versus a 20-field class.

There are some definite differences between programming with structures versus programming with classes.  If one uses immutable classes, generating from a class instance a new instance which is identical except for a few fields is difficult.  If one uses mutable classes, it can be difficult to ensure that every variable encapsulates its own set of independent values.  Suppose one has a `List<classWithPropertyX> myList`, and `myList[0]` holds an instance where `X` is 3.  One wishes to have `myList[0]` hold an instance where `X` is 4, but not affect the value of the `X` property associated with any other variable or storage location of type `classWithPropertyX`.

It's possible that the proper approach is

```
myList[0].X = 4;
```

but that could have unwanted side-effects.  Perhaps one needs to use

```
myList[0] = myList[0].WithX(4);
```

or maybe

```
var temp = myList[0];
myList[0] = new classWithPropertyX(temp.this, 4, temp.that, temp.theOther, etc.);
```

One may have to examine a lot of code to ascertain with certainty which technique is appropriate.  By contrast, if one has a `List<structWithExposedFieldX> myList` the proper code is:

```
var temp = myList[0];
temp.X = 4;
myList[0] = temp;
```

The only information one needs to know that's the correct approach is the fact that `structWithExposedFieldX` is a struct with an exposed public field `X`.